# Logging in with a non-gmail account

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, gmail, google-account

I got here an ePad running Android 2.3 and I want to set up Market on it for its owner. He doesn't have a Gmail account, neither he wants one. I have just made a Google account that is associated with an existing ISP email address.

I can successfully login with my personal email address (someone at mydomain.org) from my Iconia tablet, but this doesn't seem to be the case of older Android versions. I made the Google account from the plain old ISP address because I thought it would have worked like my case!

Am I missing something about logging in to Market with a non-gmail account? Googling around I found that somebody fixed by joining Google+, so I did with the tablet's owner, but the tablet still requires me to open a new account with a gmail email.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked like a Gingerbread-related problem.

Since Android 3.0 you can login with any Google account, with or without Gmail.

Answer (score 4):

You can only log in to the market with either your gmail account, or an account hosted with Google Apps for your domain.

This is not just to authenticate you, information is synced between your device and google servers. If you don't have an account with them, they don't know who you are. You said that you can login with your personal email address (someone at mydomain.org). I am going to guess that mydomain.org is hosting the email on google apps for your domain.

Comment: Sorry for de-accepting but I'm still unclear with something. I currently own both an HD2 with Gingerbread and an A500 with Honeycomb. From Honeycomb I can use the Google account associated to mydomain.org (I have AdWords and AdSense but no gmail, no Google-hosted email etc) but not from Gingerbread. Could it all be a Gingerbread-related problem?

Comment: Having an account associated with Google account is different then an account hosted by google. for example, when I log in to my email at foodomain.com, I am presented with a "gmail" interface, but it is not a "gmail" account. Google provides the services like email, and user management to me.

Answer (score 2):

From all my experience with The Market, You need to have a gmail account. There doesn't seem to be a way around this. [Login Android Market--Google non-gmail account?](http://androidforums.com/vibrant-support-troubleshooting/275728-login-android-market-google-non-gmail-account.html)

Answer (score 2):

To confirm - this has been resolved in later Android versions.  The wife has a phone with Android 4 and I can use my Google Account that does not have Gmail attached.  On my phone (Android 2.3.5), it requires I use a Google Account with Gmail user id.

Comment: Seems a touch irrelevant 3 years after the question was asked...

Comment: @TurboFool I beg to differ :-) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/does-it-make-sense-to-answer-old-questions Official source: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6078445?hl=en